# How does mongodb guarantee the compound index order with javascript un-ordered object literal creation?

Tags: mongodb

Such as db.products.createIndex( { "item": 1, "stock": 1 } ) 
Quoted from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

`You can specify a sort on all the keys of the index or on a subset; however, the sort keys must be listed in the same order as they appear in the index.`

As there is no order in javascript object, how could mongodb get an order from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, in the Javascript engine used by the mongo shell (SpiderMonkey) the order of fields in the object is preserved. When you call "createIndex" in the mongo shell, the shell constructs a BSON object with fields in the correct order and sends the createIndexes command to MongoDB.